# How to describe the dependencies?

Tags: composer-php

Used in the project Slim + Slim/Extras + Twig.
I need to use it https://github.com/codeguy/Slim-Extras/pull/87 ,
but at the moment pull-request not accepted.
How do I properly configure the Composer?
So far, so as not to inhibit the development, fix the code in folder vendor, but this is absolutely the wrong approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you need to add your own repository.
There might be problem in the same name of branch (origin: master, yours: master). Try changing your branch name if this happens.

```
"require": {
    "slim/extras": "master"
},

"repositories": [
    { "type": "git", "url": "https://github.com/mvader/Slim-Extras.git" }
]
```